# Pandas DataFrame mean with object

Tags: python, pandas, object, mean

I have a dataframe with 2 column nbr and tag. Nbr contain integer and tag contain Tag object.

And I want to get the mean of all the tag object (using value attribute, and the result is a new Tag with that value).

For `dataframe.add` I had the add a the `__add__` method to the Tag class.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd

class Tag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Tag(self.value + other.value)

a = Tag(2)
b = Tag(8)
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'tag': [a, b],
    'nbr': [3, 6]
})

new_tag = frame.tag.sum()
print new_tag.value  # 10
```

But for `frame.tag.mean()` I get this error `TypeError: Could not convert <__main__.Tag object at 0x7f375ac460d0> to numeric`.
Pandas first try to convert the object to float: `float(x)`, then if it fail it try this: `x = complex(x)`.

My question is their a way to make `float(tag_object)` or `complex(tag_object)` return the value attribute by adding a method to my Tag class like I did with `__add__`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the mean of all equal tag objects? Then try frame.groupby('tag').mean()

Comment: No I want to the mean of the value attribute of all the tag object

Comment: You are introducing a different type namely a user-defined *Tag* object, in your dataframe (which is a class object itself!). Your example seems very simplified and hence this reads like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide more info. What really is *Tag*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it seems like Pandas's mean coerces the results to a numeric type.

You can get close by adding the [special `__float__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) to `Tag`:

```
import pandas as pd

class Tag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Tag(self.value + other.value)
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.value)
```

Once you do so, you get

```
a = Tag(2)
b = Tag(8)
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'tag': [a, b],
    'nbr': [3, 6]
})
new_tag = frame.tag.mean()
>>> print(new_tag)
5.0
```

Note that this doesn't do exactly what you wanted (it doesn't create a `Tag` with value 5.0 - Pandas wants the result to be a numeric type).